# Creatting a Conditional formula in execl that would also search an array

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup, vlookup

**=IF(B3=1,0,IF(B3=2,$G$13*0.5,IF(B3=3,$G$13*0.25,IF(B3=4,$G$13*0.25))))**

above is the formula i am starting off with and it works. Now i need to add a little bit more to it but i am not sure on which function to use and how to implement it. Basically I need the formula to search the B column and divide by how many number **2**'s there are when the if statement is true to **B3=2**, and then divide by how many number **3**'s there are. Basically if there is a number **2** in **B3** and there are four **2**'s in the B column i need **($G$13*.25)** to be divide by 4.
thank you in an advance

Comment: Your explanation does not make sense. If B3=2 your formula calculates $G$13*0.5, but you say you want ($G$13*.25) divided by the number of 2's in column B???

Comment: That is want is inteneded. The numbers in the B column designate a certain job; the more people at at job 2 they divide job number 2's portion of the pot(ie Cell $G$13). So the way the formula reads is that job 1 gets nothing from the pot, job 2 gets 25% of the pot, and so forth. I want it to read that if there are 2 people working job 2 then they split the share of the pot that job 2 gets.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a count of a specific value in a column with the Countif() function

=COUNTIF(B:B,2)

From your problem description is not clear, where you want the count. If you want it in the section where G13 is multiplied by 0.25, then try

```
=IF(B3=1,0,IF(B3=2,$G$13*0.5,IF(B3=3,($G$13*0.25)*COUNTIF(B:B,2),IF(B3=4,$G$13*0.25))))
```

Comment: I responded to your previous comment as well, but after posting i did think of countif and implemented it and it works and this is how the formula reads. Thank you.                                                                  =IF(B3=1,$G$13*0,IF(B3=2,($G$13*0.5)/COUNTIF($B$3:$B$12,2),IF(B3=3,($G$13*0.25)/COUNTIF($B$3:$B$12,3),IF(B3=4,($G$13*0.25)/COUNTIF($B$3:$B$12,4),0))))